# a strange code appears when compileing a program that removes stopwords and apply case folding

Tags: c++, text, cpu-word

I made a code for removing stop words and then aplly a case folding on a text file called aisha

```
This is a new file I did it for mediu.
Its about Removing stopwords fRom the file
and apply casefolding to it
I Tried doing that many Times
and finally now I could do
```

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void removeStopWords(ifstream file) {
   string myArray[200];

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        {
            file >> myArray[i];

            if (myArray[i] !="is" && myArray[i]!="the" && myArray[i]!="that"&& myArray[i]!="it"&& myArray[i]!="to"){
            cout<< myArray[i]<<"  ";
            }



        } 
};

void applyCaseFolding(ifstream file) {
    file >> std::noskipws;
         char myArray[200];

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        {
            file >> myArray[i];

            if (myArray[i]=='I')
            cout<<"i";
            if (myArray[i]=='A')
            cout<<"a";
            if (myArray[i]=='T')
            cout<<"t";
            if (myArray[i]=='R')
            cout<<"r";
            else 
            if (myArray[i]!='I' && myArray[i]!='T' && myArray[i]!='R'&& myArray[i]!='A')
            cout<<myArray[i];
            }
};

int main()
{


    ifstream file("aisha.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
                      removeStopWords(file);
                      applyCaseFolding(file);


    }
    file.close();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

but the problem that when I compile the program a strange code appears on devc++
may I know whats wrong??

this is a part of the code =(

```
// Iostreams base classes -*- C++ -*-

// Copyright (C) 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004
// Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
// with this library; see the file COPYING.  If not, write to the Free
// Software Foundation, 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307,
// USA.

// As a special exception, you may use this file as part of a free software
// library without restriction.  Specifically, if other files instantiate
// templates or use macros or inline functions from this file, or you compile
// this file and link it with other files to produce an executable, this
// file does not by itself cause the resulting executable to be covered by
// the GNU General Public License.  This exception does not however
// invalidate any other reasons why the executable file might be covered by
// the GNU General Public License.

//
// ISO C++ 14882: 27.4  Iostreams base classes
//

/** @file ios_base.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  You should not attempt to use it directly.
 */

#ifndef _IOS_BASE_H
#define _IOS_BASE_H 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/atomicity.h>
#include <bits/localefwd.h>
#include <bits/locale_classes.h>

namespace std
{
  // The following definitions of bitmask types are enums, not ints,
  // as permitted (but not required) in the standard, in order to provide
  // better type safety in iostream calls.  A side effect is that
  // expressions involving them are no longer compile-time constants.
  enum _Ios_Fmtflags { _S_ios_fmtflags_end = 1L << 16 };

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator&(_Ios_Fmtflags __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return _Ios_Fmtflags(static_cast<int>(__a) & static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator|(_Ios_Fmtflags __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return _Ios_Fmtflags(static_cast<int>(__a) | static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator^(_Ios_Fmtflags __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return _Ios_Fmtflags(static_cast<int>(__a) ^ static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator|=(_Ios_Fmtflags& __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return __a = __a | __b; }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator&=(_Ios_Fmtflags& __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return __a = __a & __b; }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator^=(_Ios_Fmtflags& __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
  { return __a = __a ^ __b; }

  inline _Ios_Fmtflags
  operator~(_Ios_Fmtflags __a)
  { return _Ios_Fmtflags(~static_cast<int>(__a)); }


  enum _Ios_Openmode { _S_ios_openmode_end = 1L << 16 };

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator&(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return _Ios_Openmode(static_cast<int>(__a) & static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return _Ios_Openmode(static_cast<int>(__a) | static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator^(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return _Ios_Openmode(static_cast<int>(__a) ^ static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator|=(_Ios_Openmode& __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return __a = __a | __b; }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator&=(_Ios_Openmode& __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return __a = __a & __b; }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator^=(_Ios_Openmode& __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return __a = __a ^ __b; }

  inline _Ios_Openmode
  operator~(_Ios_Openmode __a)
  { return _Ios_Openmode(~static_cast<int>(__a)); }


  enum _Ios_Iostate { _S_ios_iostate_end = 1L << 16 };

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator&(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return _Ios_Iostate(static_cast<int>(__a) & static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator|(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return _Ios_Iostate(static_cast<int>(__a) | static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator^(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return _Ios_Iostate(static_cast<int>(__a) ^ static_cast<int>(__b)); }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator|=(_Ios_Iostate& __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return __a = __a | __b; }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator&=(_Ios_Iostate& __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return __a = __a & __b; }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator^=(_Ios_Iostate& __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
  { return __a = __a ^ __b; }

  inline _Ios_Iostate
  operator~(_Ios_Iostate __a)
  { return _Ios_Iostate(~static_cast<int>(__a)); }

  enum _Ios_Seekdir { _S_ios_seekdir_end = 1L << 16 };

  // 27.4.2  Class ios_base
  /**
   *  @brief  The very top of the I/O class hierarchy.
   *
   *  This class defines everything that can be defined about I/O that does
   *  not depend on the type of characters being input or output.  Most
   *  people will only see @c ios_base when they need to specify the full
   *  name of the various I/O flags (e.g., the openmodes).
  */
  class ios_base
  {
  public:

    // 27.4.2.1.1  Class ios_base::failure
    /// These are thrown to indicate problems.  Doc me.
    class failure : public exception
    {
    public:
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 48.  Use of non-existent exception constructor
      explicit
      failure(const string& __str) throw();

      // This declaration is not useless:
      // http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/gcc_6.html#SEC118
      virtual
      ~failure() throw();

      virtual const char*
      what() const throw();

    private:
      string _M_msg;
    };

    // 27.4.2.1.2  Type ios_base::fmtflags
    /**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:-

```
void removeStopWords(ifstream file)
```

... and

```
void applyCaseFolding(ifstream file)
```

You're trying tyo pass *copies* of the `ifstream` to these functions, and the ifstream class is not copyable. Pass references instead.

```
void applyCaseFolding(ifstream &file)
```

You don't show the exact error message, but instead you've pasted the entire code of the file where the compiler told you the error had been detected. Unfortunately, these bizarre error messages in seemingly unrelated files is one of the things that you'll just have to learn to live with as a C++ programmer. I wish it was different, but...

Comment: you are right || thanks alot